# Can't find matplotlib with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, matplotlib

I'm having some issues with matplotlib in Eclipse (on Mac),

So I've installed matplotlib because it's necessary for a project I'm working on. It works if I run it through Terminal -- but when i try to run the program or do anything with matplotlib within Eclipse, I get an error message saying that there is no module named matplotlib. I added the matplotlib folder that is within my standard site-packages folder to the system PYTHONPATH within Eclipse, but still doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same issue and could resolve it by removing any additional paths I manually added to the PYTHONPATH of the specific project.
Hope that helps
Cherio Woltan